# MS Office: Retrieve documents saved to "User Templates"

Tags: ms-office

Sometimes, seemingly at random, when I go to save a Word document I'm working on, the "Save As" defaults to "User Templates" instead of "Docs". Sometimes I don't notice its done that and I just hit "Save". Now I can't find those docs.

I found them once a while ago, but I don't recall how, and I need some of those docs for clients. How do I locate them?

Comment: Under the file menu you can open recent files, open one of those and then make a small change and do a save as it should show you where in the Save File dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

#### Via CLI

I believe Microsoft Word stores these preferences in this file: `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Word.plist`. You could use the `plutil` to view the contents or a text viewer CLI tool such as `cat`, `more` or `less`. [`.plist` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) are merely a variant of XML files.

```
$ plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.Word.plist
```

I'd look in this file for something related to "default" and "save".

#### Via GUI

If you prefer doing this through the GUI the official Microsoft Office docs show where you'd do this in this doc titled: [Save a file in Office for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-file-in-office-for-mac-421a5172-9bc6-4ef0-b452-c0939bdce786#ID0EAACAAA=Newer_versions)
.

#### References

- [My mac will not let me save word documents](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320705/my-mac-will-not-let-me-save-word-documents)
- [Can I check my “plist” files in Mac OS X for problems?](https://www.askdavetaylor.com/can_i_check_my_plist_files_in_mac_os_x_for_problems/)